# lsusb for Windows

Tags: gratis, windows-7, usb

I am looking forward to capture USB traffic with Wireshark. The tutorials I have seen use `lsusb` together with Wireshark. However, I'm on Windows.

From an `lbusb` equivalent I expect

- it is gratis
- it is a console application
- it shows USB device descriptors and the port it is connected to
- runs on Windows 7 (x64 needed) and higher, if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just recalled that I used the graphical tool [NirSoft USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html). Looking at the vendor's website, I find it can also be run as a command line tool.

**Command line** options:

```
/stext <Filename>    Save the list of all USB devices into a regular text file.
/stab <Filename>     Save the list of all USB devices into a tab-delimited text file.
/scomma <Filename>   Save the list of all USB devices into a comma-delimited text file.
/stabular <Filename> Save the list of all USB devices into a tabular text file.
/shtml <Filename>    Save the list of all USB devices into HTML file (Horizontal).
/sverhtml <Filename> Save the list of all USB devices into HTML file (Vertical).
/sxml <Filename>     Save the list of all USB devices to XML file.
```

License:

> This utility is released as **freeware**. You are allowed to freely distribute this utility via floppy disk, CD-ROM, Internet, or in any other way, as long as you don't charge anything for this. If you distribute this utility, you must include all files in the distribution package, without any modification !

System requirements:

> This utility works on Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, **Windows 7**, Windows 8, and Windows 10. Both 32-bit and **64-bit** systems are supported. Windows 98/ME is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools available for this purpose. However, and unfortunately there is not one single tool like `lsusb` which does it all. Here are your options:

- **[DevCon.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples)** (**CLI**) which is available in sources from the [github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon), or alternatively can be obtained from the Windows SDK, WDK (Windows Driver Kit) or EDWK. To [download](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) the `wdksetup.exe` run and extract the WDK for use on a separate computer. Then extract and run **only** the **`Windows Driver Kit-x86_en-us.msi`** installer. The binaries are now available under:
  `C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\Windows Kits\10\WDK\Installers\Tools\x64\devcon.exe`
- **[USBview.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview)** (**GUI & CLI**) - available in same location as above. And described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/usbview).
- **[listdevs.exe](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/examples)** (**CLI**) -  You can use some of the [libusb](https://libusb.info/) based tools found in their [github](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases). To get the latest binaries, extract the 7z release and look in examples directory.
  Example usages:

```
# listdevs.exe

0bda:0139 (bus 2, device 1) path: 8
8086:8c26 (bus 3, device 0)
8087:8008 (bus 1, device 1) path: 1
13d3:3402 (bus 2, device 3) path: 5
16c0:05df (bus 2, device 14) path: 2
8087:8000 (bus 3, device 1) path: 1
04f2:b3fd (bus 2, device 2) path: 7
046d:c52b (bus 2, device 4) path: 3
8086:8c2d (bus 1, device 0)
8086:8c31 (bus 2, device 0)

# Then use xusb to get details of the VID/PID:
# xusb.exe -i 16c0:05df

Using libusb v1.0.22.11312
Opening device 16C0:05DF...
Device properties:
        bus number: 2
         port path: 2 (from root hub)
             speed: 1.5 Mbit/s (USB LowSpeed)

Reading device descriptor:
            length: 18
      device class: 0
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 16C0:05DF
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

Reading BOS descriptor: no descriptor

Reading first configuration descriptor:
             nb interfaces: 1
              interface[0]: id = 0
interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 03.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0008
          polling interval: 0A

Claiming interface 0...

Reading string descriptors:
   String (0x01): "digistump.com"
   String (0x02): "DigiUSB"

Releasing interface 0...
Closing device...
libusb: error [parse_bos] unexpected descriptor 0 (expected f)
```

Comment: On this site we appreciate one answer per tool, as long as they are independent of each other. This makes it possible to vote and accept one of the tools only. If you post 3 tools in one answer, I might want to give you 1 upvote and 2 downvotes (which is not possible) and nobody will know which tool actually solved my problem.

Comment: This usage on this site should be described in some meta post as well.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Aha, ok, I didn't know. I'm obviously new to this site. Either way, as I mentioned, there is not any *single* tool that does what `lsusb` does, at least not unless the OP state what exact info he's looking for. In addition, the answer also depend on what you are willing to go through to get those tools. Are you willing to compile from scratch, or you just want to click and download? Do you want GUI or CLI, only? (Here he wanted CLI, AFAICT.)

Answer (score 2):

Uwe Sieber's commandline tool [RestartUsbPort](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html#restartusbport) can list present USB devices:

```
C:\>RestartUsbPort -L
RestartUsbPort V1.0.3 (Win32) - Restarts a USB Port
Freeware by Uwe Sieber - www.uwe-sieber.de

List of USB ports with a device attached:

Name      : Generic USB Hub
DeviceID  : USB\VID_8087&PID_0020\5&15BBD570&0&1
Location  : Port_#0001.Hub_#0002
DriverKey : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0004
USB Port  : 2-1

Name      : Generic USB Hub
DeviceID  : USB\VID_8087&PID_0020\5&29432BF7&0&1
Location  : Port_#0001.Hub_#0001
DriverKey : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0005
USB Port  : 3-1
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't require a console-application:

You can Download [USB-TreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/files/UsbTreeView_x64.zip) from [Uwe Sieber's website.](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html#download)
It's based on Microsoft's ["USBView" sample application](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) found in the Windows Driver Development Kit.